Can openapi-generator-maven-plugin use multiple responseWrapper classes in one module?
I try to generate Java api interface with openapi-generator-maven-plugin:
public interface MyInterface {

    ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> download(String path);

    SomeReturnType<SomeClass> upload(MultipartFile file, String entity) throws IOException;
}

Openapi-generator-maven-plugin's spring generator can be configured with responseWrapper configuration option, where response wrapper class name can be specified, but it will be applied for all endpoints.
For example, if we specify <responseWrapper>us.myorg.SomeReturnType</responseWrapper> then interface will be generated as:
public interface MyInterface {
    
     SomeReturnType<InputStreamResource> download(String path);
    
     SomeReturnType<SomeClass> upload(MultipartFile file, String entity) throws IOException;
}

Hope you can help me find a workaround. Thank you!

You are trying to generate response with different return type as per 1st example. Correct?

@vik yes, as in the 1st example

@vik After some research I found that this can be done using two extensions in openapi-generator-maven-plugin, but I think it is not a good solution.
